# Mysql is not recognized as a internal or external command

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to configure mysql with my Django project-ecomstore and I get the error given in the title,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # 
        'NAME': 'ecomstore',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Python27\Djangoprojects\ecomstore>python manage.py dbshell
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: are able to access mysql via shell

Comment: Its more a mysql question than a django one...i am going to retag it

Answer (score 1):

Just use `'ENGINE': 'mysql',`. That's how my current app has it.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that the ‘mysql’ excutable command file (mysql.exe) was not added to your system path therefore the system was unable to locate this file. To add the ‘mysql’ to system path try to locate the ‘mysql’ resident folder.

Seems you are using windows, here are the steps:

1) go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> System

2)paste "mysql resident folder path" into Variable value: field of Edit System Variable pop up.

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py dbshell` is just a shortcut for `mysql -d DATABASENAME -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD` and you will need to have mysql installed on your system and that mysql command should be able to run from the console.